# Simultaneously diagonalisable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f$ and $g$ be two diagonalisable endomorphisms in a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{K}$. I want to show that if $f\circ g=g\circ f$ (they commute) then they are simultaneously diagonalisable.

A proof from Fischer - "Lineare Algebra" p.239 goes as follows:

We can build the direct sums 
$V=Eig_{\lambda_1,f}\oplus ... \oplus Eig_{\lambda_k,f}\\
=Eig_{\mu_1,g}\oplus ... \oplus Eig_{\mu_l,g}$

where $Eig_{\lambda_1, f}$ is the eigenspace of $f$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ . We fix a $\lambda$ and set $W=Eig_{\lambda,f}$.

If $w\in W$, it follows that $f(g(w))=g(f(w))=g(\lambda w)=\lambda g(w)$, so $W$ is $g$-invariant.

Furthermore, we set $W_j=W\cap Eig_{\mu_j,g}$ for $j=1,...,l$.

It suffices to show that $W=\bigoplus_{i=1}^l W_i$, because we can generalise for all eigenvalues of $f$. Since we know that the sum of eigenspaces is always direct, we only need to show a simple sum.

For $w\in W$ there is a $w_j\in Eig(\mu_j,g)$,such that $w=\sum_{i=1}^lw_i$. It follows that
$f(w)=\sum_{i=1}^lf(w_i)=\lambda w=\sum_{i=1}^l\lambda w_i$ and because of the uniqueness of the sum we have $f(w_j)=\lambda w_j$ for every $j$ and we are done.

I don't understand why we need the $g$ invariance of $W$ (which we derived from the fact, that the matrices commute).

Answer (score 1):

If $g:V\to V$ is a diagonalisable linear transformation, and $W\subset V$ a $g-$invariant subspace of $V$ then $g:W\to W$ is also diagonalisable, since the minimum polynomial of $g$ kills $g|_W$ as well, and hence the minimum polynomial of $g|_W$ has only simple roots.

Hence, there is a basis of $W$ consisting of eigenvectors of $g$.